# Getting error when deploying MERN app with zeit(now)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern, vercel

I have completed a tutorial on the MERN stack and want to deploy my project with zeit's now.  However, whenever I do deploy my application(with all the default create-react-app parameters), it gives me this error: Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 254.  Here is the GitHub(I imported a GitHub project) with all of my code: https://github.com/Stick-z/MERN-Shopping